# PowerShell - count accdb rows for all the files in folder at once

Tags: powershell, ms-access, count, powershell-3.0

I know I can count how many rows a csv has without opening it by using powershell.
example:

```
import-csv C:\MyFolde\myfile.csv | Measure-Object
```

I need to do this for multiple access files (.accdb). This time for every (and all) file/s in a given folder, and then I want to sum the rows up (total sum for all the files in that folder combined). Is there a solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: An Access file has tables (with records), not rows.

Comment: asume each access file has only one table with records.

Comment: Also just to be clear regarding terminology, the file most definitely does get opened when you use Import-CSV.

Comment: I meant, without me opening it. I'm sure you understand what I want. It would be great if I can find a solution to this. Because opening each access file and writing in a file the number of rows and at the end sum them up will take so much time

Comment: That is kind of my point. If they were for instance a bunch of CSV files, the time taken would be exactly the same amount of time as if you explicitly opened and read each file. There is no magic involved. To see (count) what is in the file, you open the file and look at it. The same is true for Access DB files. You would need to use the JET driver and an ADODB connection and open each DB and look at it.

Comment: "Opening each access file" using the Access Database Engine (or perhaps even ACE DAO) is almost certainly what you're going to have to do.

Comment: If they were a bunch of csv files. Isn't there a way to use a foreach item in the folder, then measure the object save the count in a variable, the same for the next file and increment the variable? I don't posses enough powershell knowledge to do this, but this should be a way, right? And maybe the same thing for the accdb with some modifications. Right?

Comment: Import-CSV is simply a cmdlet that opens the file, reads the file and outputs the contents of the file. It is syntactical shorthand. You may or may not be able to find where an individual has written a similar function or cmdlet for access DBs. Given the general craptitude of access DBs in general though I would find it highly unlikely that anyone has taken the time to do so.

Comment: There are two votes to close the question as unclear. How is this in any way unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the benefit of future visitors, here is a PowerShell script that counts all of the rows in the non-system tables of every .accdb file in the specified folder:

```
$connStrStub = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
$numFiles = 0
$numTables = 0
$totalRows = 0
foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Public\test\*.accdb)
{
    $numFiles++
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection ($connStrStub + $f.FullName)
    $conn.Open()
    $schemaTable = $conn.GetSchema("TABLES")
    foreach ($dtRow in $schemaTable)
    {
        $tblName = $dtRow["TABLE_NAME"]
        if (!$tblName.StartsWith("MSys"))
        {
            $numTables++
            $cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM [$tblName]", $conn
            $totalRows += $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        }
    }
    $conn.Close()
}
write-output "files: $numFiles"
write-output "user_tables: $numTables"
write-output "total_rows: $totalRows"
```

Comment: This a good answer! Thank you! Even if I have solved my problem, I will mark your answer as accepted since this a good solution for the problem

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to use powershell.
However I managed to count all the rows by using SQl Service Integration Services. Used a foreach (to loop through all the files), inside of the loop a task which has a select count from each file and outputs the result into an xls.

Thank you all for your time